# React.js communicate with state object from outside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Using the [React DnD](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd/) lib:

```
const itemDropTarget = {
    acceptDrop(component, item) {
        window.alert('You dropped ' + item.name + '!');
    }
};

const Container = React.createClass({

    mixins: [DragDropMixin],

    getInitialState() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
    },

    statics: {
        configureDragDrop(register) {
            register(ItemTypes.ITEM, {
                dropTarget: itemDropTarget
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Wondering how I can add the new "dropped" item into my React component's `state` object, from the `acceptDrop` function? What's the usual approach for this kind of thing with React?

Comment: I've never used this component, but it looks like the first argument passed to the callback is the React component. Can you use that to manipulate the state?

Comment: You are very correct. Ended up doing something similar to what you're saying @WiredPrairie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way is using callbacks , you create the function inside the parent component and then put it as props when you call the child.